# Converting Nested json data to table format in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-fullstack

I have nested json data as below(coming from api) :

{
"count":28,
"value":[
{
"id":"dbff7b54",
"name":"cleansed",
"description":"for business",
"url":"https://www.google.com",
"state":"wellFormed",
"revision":745,
"visibility":"private",
"lastUpdateTime":"2021-02-23T08:57:34.26Z"
},
{
"id":"7051f961",
"name":"pub",
"description":"for testing",
"url":"https://wikipedia.com",
"state":"wellFormed",
"revision":9690,
"visibility":"private",
"lastUpdateTime":"2020-08-21T13:06:13.97Z"
}
]
}

I need to process this nested json into table format using react(without material-ui),this json data will be using for visualization also and i need count also.

Can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You just get `obj.value` and loop through data.
It should look like this:

```js
obj.value.map(item => {
  return (
    <tr>
        <td>{ item.id } </td>
        <td>{ item.name } </td>
        <td>{ item.description } </td>
        <td>{ item.url } </td>
        <td>{ item.revision } </td>
        <td>{ item.visibility } </td>
        <td>{ item.lastUpdateTime } </td>
    </tr>
  )
})
```